# Wordpress listing estranger results in google

Tags: wordpress, spam

I have a wordpress web site and when I list the results in google I see a lot of garbage results in google, I see results such as: 
-Buy Levitra Extra Dosage in Sierra Leone Freetown 
-Buy Kamagra Soft in Norfolk Island Kingston -- Shop Kamagra
-Canadian pharmacy cialis pfizer -- Cialis on sale, Cia
-Obtain Extra Super Viagra - accept ACH -- Buy Extra 
But, the links really doesn't exist in the wordpress, if I click them, the result is not found. Any idea about how can I identify what produced that results? I am using a paid template, so it should be safe. (in theory)

Thank you

Comment: https://wordpress.org/support/article/faq-my-site-was-hacked/

Comment: Being it a paid theme doesn't make it safe. Also, the issue isn't necessarily caused by the theme: it could be a plugin, or if you're using a shared hosting it might be even coming from an infected site in the same server. Check the link Ilmari posted above and follow the suggestions mentioned there.

Answer (score 1):

1. Update your themes & plugins & WordPress installation.  Do a malware scan, you can use wordfence.
2. Add your own metadata, description & other SEO details, you can use Yoast for this.
3. After doing Create and Submit a Sitemap to Google Search Console

Answer (score 0):

It's quite possible that your site is infected. Scan your site using one of these plugins: [malCure Malware Removal & Firewall](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-malware-removal/), [GOTMLS](https://wordpress.org/plugins/gotmls/) and it will detect malware / malicious code. You can inspect the database & files and clean them manually. You can also follow this guide: https://www.webarxsecurity.com/comprehensive-wordpress-malware-removal-guide/ or ask for professional help.